# Unable to Change UILabel.text from another View Controller, UILabel gets nil value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a newbie programmer and trying to create a Single View weather application. My goal is editing ***dateLbl1*** created in ***WeeklyWeatherViewController*** from ***HomeViewController***.

I wrote my code like this :

```
let WeeklyWeatherView = WeeklyWeatherViewController()
...
WeeklyWeatherView.dateLbl1.text = nextDayShort[0].uppercased()
```

But the label gets "nil" value.

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

*(nextDayShort is not nil, and I connected UILabel to Storyboard)*

Searched the web for my issue and tried calling ViewController as :

`var swipePage: WeeklyWeatherViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyStoryboard")`

I get this error :

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I read about passing data between View Controllers but couldn't use them in my code at all. How can I fix this issue?
Thank you for any help!

HomeViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

let DateView = DateViewController()
let WeatherView = WeatherViewController()
let WeeklyWeatherView = WeeklyWeatherViewController()



var currentHour : String?
var currentDay: String?
var nextDayShort = [String]()
var listCount = 0

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var backgroudView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var daysView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timeView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var splashImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var middleView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rightView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var leftView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var middleHourBGView: UIView!
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
           switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
                case .restricted, .denied:
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Locations servies are disabled!", message: "Please go to settings and allow location services or the application can't fetch weather data.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                   
                    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
                        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) else {
                            return
                        }

                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                        }
                    }
                   
                   alert.addAction(settingsAction)
                   let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
                   alert.addAction(cancelAction)

                   self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
                case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                   print("Access")
            
                @unknown default:
                break
            }
        } else {
            print("Location services are not enabled")
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        styleUI()
    }
    
    private func styleUI(){
        daysView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        daysView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        daysView.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
        daysView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        
        middleView.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        middleHourBGView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        let now = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        let hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
        
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd,YYYY EEEE"
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: now)
        DateView.dateLbl?.text = dateString
        currentHour = String(hour)
        
        
        let formatter2 = DateFormatter()
        
        for n in 1..<6 {
            var dayComponent = DateComponents()
            dayComponent.day = n
            let theCalendar = Calendar.current
            let nextDate = theCalendar.date(byAdding: dayComponent, to: Date())
            formatter2.dateFormat = "EE"
            let nextDaySh = formatter2.string(from: nextDate! as Date)
            nextDayShort.append(nextDaySh)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            WeeklyWeatherView.dateLbl1.text = nextDayShort[0].uppercased()
            WeeklyWeatherView.dateLbl2.text = nextDayShort[1].uppercased()
            WeeklyWeatherView.dateLbl3.text = nextDayShort[2].uppercased()
            WeeklyWeatherView.dateLbl4.text = nextDayShort[3].uppercased()
            WeeklyWeatherView.dateLbl5.text = nextDayShort[4].uppercased()
        }
        
        if (hour > 5 && hour < 21) {
            backgroudView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            timeView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            daysView.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3333333433, green: 0.3333333433, blue: 0.3333333433, alpha: 1)
        } else {
            backgroudView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.0862745098, green: 0.09411764706, blue: 0.3058823529, alpha: 1)
            timeView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.0862745098, green: 0.09411764706, blue: 0.3058823529, alpha: 1)
            DateView.cityLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            DateView.dateLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            DateView.tempLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            daysView.layer.shadowColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            WeatherView.leftHourLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            WeatherView.leftTempLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            WeatherView.rightHourLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            WeatherView.rightTempLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            WeatherView.middleTempLbl.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        weather.getWeather(lat: location.latitude, lon: location.longitude) { weather in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                DateView.cityLbl.text  = weather.city.name
                DateView.tempLbl.text  = "\(Int(round(weather.list[0].main.temp)) - 273)°"
                WeeklyWeatherView.tempLbl1.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list[1].main.temp)) - 273)°"
                WeeklyWeatherView.tempLbl2.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list[2].main.temp)) - 273)°"
                WeeklyWeatherView.tempLbl3.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list[3].main.temp)) - 273)°"
                WeeklyWeatherView.tempLbl4.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list[4].main.temp)) - 273)°"
                WeeklyWeatherView.tempLbl5.text = "\(Int(round(weather.list[5].main.temp)) - 273)°"
                
                self.splashImage.isHidden = true
            }
        }

    }
}
```

WeeklyWeatherViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let storyBoardEdit = StoryboardEditor()
let weather = WeatherAPI()

class WeeklyWeatherViewController: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dateLbl5: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLbl1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLbl2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLbl3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLbl4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tempLbl5: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherImg1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherImg2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherImg3: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherImg4: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var weatherImg5: UIImageView!
    
    
    func fillUI(){
        
        dateLbl1.text = nil
        
        var dayId = [String]()
        for x in 1..<6 {
            dayId.append("03d")
            let dayIdInt = Int(dayId[x-1])!
            let imageIDName = storyBoardEdit.editWeatherIcons(dayIDInt: dayIdInt)
            
            switch x {
            case 1:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.weatherImg1.image = UIImage(named: imageIDName)
                }
            case 2:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.weatherImg2.image = UIImage(named: imageIDName)
                }
            case 3:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.weatherImg3.image = UIImage(named: imageIDName)
                }
            case 4:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.weatherImg4.image = UIImage(named: imageIDName)
                }
            case 5:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.weatherImg5.image = UIImage(named: imageIDName)
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please share your full code ...

Comment: @jawadAli Added, thanks.

Comment: do not declare you view controller as @IBOutlet

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the extra advice, I updated my code and post.

Comment: If it's in Storyboard, you should indeed use the second method. BUT, I think that the issue is that's the view is not loaded, so the outlet's aren't too. You aren't presenting the viewcontroller? Why are you setting its label values then? Are you already presenting one? If so, you created a whole new object, not the one already existing.

Comment: If you want to access/set values on a succeeding viewController you may wanna use the `prepareForSegue` method to do so.

Comment: I think your @IBOutlet of dateLbl1 is not connected with storyboard. 
Also one question: How you design your view called *WeeklyWeatherViewController* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this changes:

- In your Storyboard (or Xib), update the class of your `weatherView` to `WeeklyWeatherViewController`  and reset the outlet. You should get it in this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var weatherView: WeeklyWeatherViewController!
```

- Delete the following line:

```
let WeeklyWeatherView = WeeklyWeatherViewController()
```

- In your `styleUI()` method replace the lines using `WeeklyWeatherView` by this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    weeklyWeatherView.dateLbl1.text = nextDayShort[0].uppercased()
    weeklyWeatherView.dateLbl2.text = nextDayShort[1].uppercased()
    weeklyWeatherView.dateLbl3.text = nextDayShort[2].uppercased()
    weeklyWeatherView.dateLbl4.text = nextDayShort[3].uppercased()
    weeklyWeatherView.dateLbl5.text = nextDayShort[4].uppercased()
}
```

In your locationManager() function, replace the lines using `WeeklyWeatherView` by this:

```
weeklyWeatherView.tempLbl1.text = "\Int(round(weather.list[1].main.temp)) - 273)º"
weeklyWeatherView.tempLbl2.text = "\Int(round(weather.list[2].main.temp)) - 273)º"
weeklyWeatherView.tempLbl3.text = "\Int(round(weather.list[3].main.temp)) - 273)º"
weeklyWeatherView.tempLbl4.text = "\Int(round(weather.list[4].main.temp)) - 273)º"
weeklyWeatherView.tempLbl5.text = "\Int(round(weather.list[5].main.temp)) - 273)º"
```

See that I'm using the newly created outlet in both cases, right?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I edited my code like this "let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let WeeklyWeatherView = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()" but got "Value of type 'UIViewController?' has no member 'dateLbl1'".

Comment: I updated the answer with my guess on what you are really trying to do in your code, can you check it out? @EdwardMordrake

Comment: Thank you again for your great answer. I followed the steps but got several errors. For "guard let controller...." line : "Cannot convert value of type 'WeeklyWeatherViewController?' to expected argument type 'String', Expected ',' separator, Expected expression in list of expressions". For "controller.didMove..." line: "Expected 'else' after 'guard' condition"

Comment: Sorry about that... Missed a closing parenthesis in that `guard let` statement, fixed it.

Comment: I am really grateful for your effort. I tried the code after your last edit and still got some errors. You can see from here : https://i.imgur.com/JFsREGN.png

Comment: I'm really sorry, I did not realise your WeeklyWeatherViewController was a UIView, I thought it was a UIViewController, that method would do the job if it was the case. I'm updating it to usage with a UIView, just a second

Comment: Sorry for not specify my view's class, I totally forgot. I just updated my code and syntax errors gone. When I run my application, I get " EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)" for " self.weatherView.dateLbl4.text = nextDayShort[3].uppercased()" line. There are 2 more lines identical with this, but I get error in third line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you have initialized the `WeeklyWeatherViewController`

```
let WeeklyWeatherView = WeeklyWeatherViewController()
```

This view has an associated xib from where you have created the connection. Now When you are initializing your `WeeklyWeatherViewController` class that time your xib view is not been initialized.

You need to load the nib file in the `init` method in your `WeeklyWeatherViewController`.

```
class WeeklyWeatherViewController: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    
        let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("your_nib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView
        addSubview(contentView!)
    
        // set constraints for contentView.
    }

    convenience init() {
        let defaultFrame = //provide your default frame
        self.init(frame: defaultFrame)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

So the thing is when you have an associated xib file, in short when you are supplying your view from outside you need to initialize that external view and attach it to your class. That way your view will still remain the memory and you can access all the connected `IBOutlet`.